# iTunes only showing Purchased Music

Tags: itunes

My iTunes is suddenly only showing music purchased through iTunes.  I have tried renaming the files per as mentioned on [this Apple Support Communities thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4899894?tstart=0) and had no luck.  I am also not using iTunes Match.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have hidden the navigation menu on the left side? Perhaps you have selected the "purchased" tab and then hidden the menu

Answer (score -1):

In iTunes go to "File" -> "Import Folders" then simply select **all** the folders from your "iTunes Music". They will be sent to your library!